# How Can I undo a commit in my git bluemix panel?

Tags: git, github, ibm-cloud

*I don´t see option for undo a commit in my git panel Bluemix*

Comment: Git is intended to KEEP the history, not change or delete it. Of course, there are methods to do so, but changing history is bad practice 90% of the time. I suggest looking for a method to reverse the commit using another.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the instructions to revert the commit here: https://hub.jazz.net/docs/git/#revert

> 1. Under History, select a commit.
> 2. On the right side of the page, above the commit summary, click the revert icon Revert icon.

Answer (score 0):

You have to revert your code to the desired code revision through the revert function (already suggested on other answers)
Then to propagate the change to your running bluemix application, you have to pull the changes locally and push your application source code again, or manually trigger a build&deploy action if you are deploying by DevOps service